# N-ary tree depth and degree algorithm

Tags: java, depth, n-ary-tree

I'm having some problems with a couple algorithms that should return the maximum degree (the max number of children of a node) and depth (dimension of the longest branch) of a tree. It looks like with some Tree structures they work, with some others they don't. Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong with the code?

My Tree structure is

```
public class Tree<T> {

  public Node<T> root;

  public Tree() {
    root = null;
  }
```

My Node structure is:

```
public class Node<T>{
  public T elem; 
  private Node<T> father;
  private Node<T> child; 
  private Node<T> sibling;
  private T epsilon;

public Node(T elem){   
  this.elem = elem;
  this.father = null;
  this.child = null;
  this.sibling = null;  
}
```

The degree algorithm is:

```
public int degree(){
int breadth = 0;
int max = 0;
return auxDegree(this.root, breadth, max);
}

public int auxDegree(Node<T> node, int count, int maxChild){
if(node!=null){
  if(node.getChild()!=null){ 
    maxChild = Math.max(auxDegree(node.getChild(), 0, maxChild), auxDegree(node.getSibling(), 0, maxChild));
    count = countSibling(node.getChild()) + 1;
    return (count>maxChild) ? count : maxChild;
  }else return maxChild;
 }else return maxChild;
}
```

Finally, the depth algorithm:

```
public int depth(){
  int deepness = 0;
  return auxDepth(this.root, deepness);
}

public int auxDepth(Node<T> node, int maxDepth){
  if(node!=null){
    if(node.getChild()!=null){
       maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, auxDepth(node.getChild(), maxDepth));
       maxDepth = maxDepth + 1;
       return maxDepth;
    }else{
      return maxDepth;
    }
  }else return maxDepth;
}
```

The Insert code is:

```
public Node<T> search(T key){
  return searchAux(this.root, key);
}

private Node<T> searchAux(Node<T> node, T key){
  if(node == null) 
    return null;
  else{
    while(node.getChild() != null && key != node.getElem()){
      node = node.getChild();
      searchAux(node.getSibling(), key); 
    }
  }  
   return node;  
}

public void insert(T father_key, T child_key){
  if(IsEmpty())
    this.root = new Node<T>(child_key);
  else{
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>(child_key);
    Node<T> father = search(father_key);
    if(father.getChild() == null){
      father.setChild(node);
      node.setParent(father);
     }else{
     if (father.getChild() != null){
       Node<T> brother = father.getChild(); 
       while(brother.getSibling() != null){
         brother = brother.getSibling(); 
       }
       brother.setSibling(node);
       node.setParent(father);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The structure that are not working are:

```
public void Test_Depth(){
  tree.insert(null, e2);
  tree.insert(e2, e3);
  tree.insert(e2, e1);
  tree.insert(e3, e4);
  tree.insert(e4, e5);
  tree.insert(e5, e6);
  tree.insert(e6, e7);
  assertEquals(6,tree.depth());
}
```

This returns 5 but should return 6

```
public void Test_Depth(){
  tree.insert(null, e1);
  tree.insert(e1, e2);
  tree.insert(e1, e3);
  tree.insert(e3, e4);
  tree.insert(e3, e5);
  tree.insert(e3, e6);
  assertEquals(3,tree.degree());
}
```

This should return 3 but returns 2

e1 to e7 are integers.

Comment: I think providing the "bad" and "good" tree structures would help to analyse the problem.

Comment: I added them. Sorry for not doing so. The thing is, they work on almost anything I tried except those two and a couple more

Comment: Can you show us your insert(...) implementation?

Comment: Done. The Insert method uses a Search auxiliary method. If you need any clarification please tell me

Comment: What's the type of `e1`..`e7`?

Comment: They're integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First and foremost, your `searchAux` function is wrong. The following line is useless, because its return value is ignored:

```
searchAux(node.getSibling(), key);
```

Moreover, the `while` loop allows for children nodes to be assigned to wrong parents. The condition

```
node.getChild() != null && key != node.getElem()
```

is false if the node you're visiting has no children, regardless of its key value; this means that the ensuing `return node;` instruction might be executed *even if the node you are returning is not the parent node you are looking for*.

This is what happens, for instance, in your second example. This is the situation after the first three `insert`s (vertical line = parent-child, horizontal line = sibling):

```
e1
|
e2--e3
```

So far so good. When you call `tree.insert(e3, e4)`, though, e3 is visited but ignored; e2 is returned in its stead (try and walk through your code). Thus:

```
e1
|
e2--e3
|
e4
```

This is what the second tree looks like in the end, by the way:

```
e1
|
e2--e3
|
e4
|
e5
|
e6
```

Second: the first tree is correct, as far as I can tell, even though your search algorithm is wrong. Its depth is 5, not 6 (depth of root node is zero):

```
0: e2
   |
1: e3--e1
   |
2: e4
   |
3: e5
   |
4: e6
   |
5: e7
```

That being said, here's a quick draft for a recursive depth-first search:

```
private Node<T> searchAux(Node<T> node, T key){
    if(node == null) 
        return null;
    if (node.getElem() == key)
        return node;
    if (node.getChild() != null) {
        Node<T> foundNode = searchAux(node.getChild(), key);
        if (foundNode != null)
            return foundNode;
    } 
    return searchAux(node.getSibling(), key);
}
```

(On a side note, you don't need `else`s after `return`s.)

Comment: Ok. Now Insert should work. I verifyed with various Trees. Still, Depth and Degree methods aren't working.

Comment: At a first glance, the `auxDepth` methods never visits siblings. Try to fix that.

Comment: I changed the two methods using a while to visit all siblings and it's working. Thanks a lot for the help!